# Creating m n-column dataframes from n m-column dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

What's the cleanest way of converting a list of m n-column dataframes into a list of n m-column dataframes? Specifically, I want the the first n-column dataframe to contain all first columns from the m-column dataframes, the second n-column dataframe to contain all second columns from the m-column dataframes, and so on. At the same time I'd like to assign new names to the columns.

```py
m, n = 3, 2
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(1, 10, (4, m)), columns=["a", "b", "c"])
    for _ in range(n)
]
```

```
# dfi1
   a  b  c
0  2  7  9
1  9  4  3
2  1  6  1
3  7  7  2
# dfi2
   a  b  c
0  5  6  2
1  8  7  1
2  2  8  5
3  9  6  1
```

Target:

```
# dfo1
  foo bar
0  2  5
1  9  8
2  1  2
3  7  9
# dfo2
  foo bar
0  7  6
1  4  7
2  6  8
3  7  6
# dfo3
  foo bar
0  9  2
1  3  1
2  1  5
3  2  1
```

There's probably a better way than two verbose nested for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

```py
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, keys=('foo','bar')).unstack(0)
dfs1 = [df1.xs(i, axis=1, level=0) for i in df1.columns.levels[0]]
# or
dfs1 = [df.droplevel(0, axis=1) for i, df in df1.groupby(axis=1, level=0)]
```

**Step by step**

```
np.random.seed(2019)
m, n = 3, 2
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(1, 10, (4, m)), columns=["a", "b", "c"])
    for _ in range(n)
]
print (dfs)
[   a  b  c
0  9  3  6
1  9  7  9
2  1  1  8
3  9  6  4,    a  b  c
0  1  3  6
1  8  9  6
2  5  1  2
3  7  1  3]
```

First use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with keys parameter by list of tuple with same size like length of `n`, then use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape for `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = pd.concat(dfs, keys=('foo','bar')).unstack(0)
print (df1)
    a       b       c    
  foo bar foo bar foo bar
0   9   1   3   3   6   6
1   9   8   7   9   9   6
2   1   5   1   1   8   2
3   9   7   6   1   4   3
```

Then create list of `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs1 = [df1.xs(i, axis=1, level=0) for i in df1.columns.levels[0]]
print (dfs1)
[   foo  bar
0    9    1
1    9    8
2    1    5
3    9    7,    foo  bar
0    3    3
1    7    9
2    1    1
3    6    1,    foo  bar
0    6    6
1    9    6
2    8    2
3    4    3]
```

Or:

```
dfs1 = [df.droplevel(0, axis=1) for i, df in df1.groupby(axis=1, level=0)]
print (dfs1)
[   foo  bar
0    9    1
1    9    8
2    1    5
3    9    7,    foo  bar
0    3    3
1    7    9
2    1    1
3    6    1,    foo  bar
0    6    6
1    9    6
2    8    2
3    4    3]
```

Comment: Great answer (once again)! Mind if I (or you) add a short summary with just the relevant code at the top?

Comment: @Casimir - Can you explain more? But if think my answer should be improved, I have no problem with it, I like it ;)